# How to force text in a primefaces datatable to fill the whole column

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have several cases where the text would actually fit inside a fixed-size column, but it is cut off at approx 70% of the column width.This looks really awkward. Unfortunately I have no idea how to influence this.

Maybe overriding the settings in the `.ui-dt-c` class (used by the dynamically generated columns) would help, but I have no idea how.

I have tried using both `style="width:50"` and `width="50"` for setting the column width - with no effect on the cropping.

Thank you.

I am using Primefaces 3.3.1 with Mojarra 2.1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style="width:50"` is incorrect css. You'd need to either specify pixels or percent like this:

```
style="width:50px"
```

or

```
style="width:50%"
```